# AbortBroadcast in Receiver and Re-Issue in IntentService

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` in which the application is listening for the incoming SMS, im starting an `IntentService` in `onReceive` method of the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            this.abortBroadcast();
            context.startService(new Intent(context,MyIntentService.class));
        }
}
```

in the `onReceive` method im aborting the broadcast. I want to clear the broadcast in the `IntentService` based on a condition so the SMS goes to the inbox else not, how can i do that? Can i re-issue a broadcast so the message is saved in inbox and by-passes `MyBroadcastReceiver`

Regards.

Comment: Y dont you check the condition in the receiver??

Comment: because it takes time and in the mean while another sms arrives it messes things up...so i start an IntentService which completes the task before starting another task and it also runs on background thread, so...

Comment: The **if(condition){}** in your code taking much time??

Comment: @Namecan'tbedisplayed yup

Comment: can you suggest anything?

Comment: if just the condition is written in receiver, you can abort receiver based on the condition, and maintain some flag and send to the service thru the intent , In the Service you can know whether it is aborted or not, so that you can perform the required actions.

Comment: Any solutions you found??

Comment: nope, had to live with it for the time being.... i cant actually move the `if` inside the receiver

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            if(prefs.getBoolean("<KEY>", true)){
                 context.startService(new Intent(context,MyIntentService.class));
            }
    }
}
```

In intentService if your condition satisfies set `Boolean` with your key to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to clear the broadcast in the IntentService based on a condition so the SMS goes to the inbox else not, how can i do that?

That is not possible, sorry.

> Can i re-issue a broadcast so the message is saved in inbox and by-passes MyBroadcastReceiver

That too is not possible, sorry.

And since your entire app will not work on Android 4.4+, I would recommend that you reconsider what you are doing. The SMS message always will be received by the user's chosen SMS client on Android 4.4+.

Comment: tnx for the valueable info, can you please clarify why it would not work on 4.4+

Comment: means no matter what i do `abortBroadcast()` the chosen app shall receive the SMS??

Comment: @Johnx: "means no matter what i do abortBroadcast() the chosen app shall receive the SMS?" -- correct.